# What are all stanzas of "Jane Kaha Gaye Wo Din" by Hasrat Jaipuri?

Tags: lyrics, filmi

I'm talking about an Indian old Hindi song "Jane Kaha Gaye Wo Din" sung by my favorite singer [Mukesh Chand Mathur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukesh_(singer)) (1923-1976). Some information is as follows:

Film: Mera Naam Joker (1970)
Music Director: Shankar Jaikishan
Lyricist: Hasrat Jaipuri

Actually only following two stanzas are heard in the song:

> **1.** mere kadam jaha pade, sajde kiye the yaar ne
> mere kadam jaha pade, sajde kiye the yaar ne
> mujhko rula rula diya, jati hui bahar ne
> jane kaha gaye wo din...

> **2.** apani nazar me aaj kal, din bhi andheri raat hai
> apani nazar me aaj kal, din bhi andheri raat hai
> saya hi apne sath tha, saya hi apne sath hai
> jane kaha gaye vo din....

I heard the **third stanza** for the first time in this linked version of [Mukesh's live concert in 1976, USA](https://youtu.be/lxXWKybH68I?t=3m):

> **3.** is dil ke aasiyan me, unke khayal reh gaye
> is dil ke aasiyan me, unke khayal reh gaye
> tod ke wo dil chal diye, hum phir akele rahe gaye
> jane kaha gaye vo din...

Another two stanzas I've recently heard in [this video of a stage show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1sJhzbB120) by Dr. Kamlesh Avasthi, which are as follows:

> **4.** andhiya gam ki yu chali. sapne mere bikhar gaye
> andhiya gam ki yu chali. sapne mere bikhar gaye
> aasu bhi mere puchhne lage, sathi tere kidhar gaye
> jane kaha gaye vo din...

> **5.** hamne to apna jan kar, unko gale lagaya tha
> hamne to apna jan kar, unko gale lagaya tha
> patthar ko hamne poojkar, unko khuda banayatha
> jane kaha gaye vo din...

Now, the motive of posting this question is that [Kamlesh Avasthi mentioned (in that show)](https://youtu.be/M1sJhzbB120?t=2m56s) that **there are 13 stanzas written for this song**. So, I'm looking for all the 13 stanzas of this song. I mean 7 stanzas in addition to 5 I've quoted above.

<sup>Note: The language of all the lines quoted above is Hindi.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is one more stanza ([source](https://www.bobbytalkscinema.com/recentpost/The-rare-unheard-antras-of--1107)):

> Yeh jindgi bhi bahar hai,
> sajde me unke yaar hai
> Do din to hamse mil gaye,
> dil ko yahi karar hai

Some more lines are given [here](https://www.hindigeetmala.net/song/jane_kahan_gaye_woh_din.htm):

> kal khel me hum ho na ho gardish me tare rahenge sada (2)
> bhuloge ke tum, bhulenge vo
> par hum tumhare rahenge sada
> rahenge yahi apne nisha, iske siva jana kahan
> ji chahe jab humko aawaz do
> hum hai wahi hum the jaha
> apne yahi dono jaha iske siva jana kahan
>
> kal khel me hum ho na ho gardish me tare rahenge sada (2)
> bhuloge ke tum, bhulenge vo
> par hum tumhare rahenge sada
> rahenge yahi apne nisha, iske siva jana kahan
> jeena yaha marna yaha, iske siva jana kahan (3)

Comment: "kal khel me hum ho na ho " is from another song